# Json request from https to http not working in IE 9 or under via Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer

I use JQuery ajax to get Json data cross domain. My code works under Firefox and Chrome, but IE is a big headache. It works in I.E. 10, but not less than that. I need to get it worked at less IE8 or above because they are still the majority. Here is my code:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;   
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https:xxx.com",
    crossDomain: true,

    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",

    headers : {
        "Accept-Datetime" :  "Tue, 12 Feb 2013 00:00:00 GMT",
        "Authorization" : "Basic XXXXXXXX"
    },

    success: processDetailsViewData,
   error: function(xhr, status, error){ 
   console.log(xhr.responseText, status, error);
   }
});
```

I tried using jQuery.XDomainRequest.js, it works only in between only http or only https. I dont need any call backs, and I need to include "Accept-Datetime" and "Authorization" in the request. So I guess I do not need to use JsonP. Anybody deal with this case before? cheers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Be sure that your URL allow ajax request.
2. Be sure to have a crossdomain.xml on the targeted
3. Some crossdomain request doesn't work find with jquery in IE, so you will have to override ajax function in Jquery library.

--

to allow ajax in the target with PHP:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

--

you can download html5boilerplate to find a crossdomain.xml example

--

to override jquery method you can try this

```
(function( jQuery ) {

if ( window.XDomainRequest && !jQuery.support.cors ) {
    jQuery.ajaxTransport(function( s ) {
        if ( s.crossDomain && s.async ) {
            if ( s.timeout ) {
                s.xdrTimeout = s.timeout;
                delete s.timeout;
            }
            var xdr;
            return {
                send: function( _, complete ) {
                    function callback( status, statusText, responses, responseHeaders ) {
                        xdr.onload = xdr.onerror = xdr.ontimeout = xdr.onprogress = jQuery.noop;
                        xdr = undefined;
                        jQuery.event.trigger( "ajaxStop" );
                        complete( status, statusText, responses, responseHeaders );
                    }
                    xdr = new XDomainRequest();
                    xdr.open( s.type, s.url );
                    xdr.onload = function() {
                        var status = 200;
                        var message = xdr.responseText;
                        var r = jQuery.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);
                        if (r.StatusCode && r.Message) {
                            status = r.StatusCode;
                            message = r.Message;
                        }
                        callback( status , message, { text: message }, "Content-Type: " + xdr.contentType );
                    };
                    xdr.onerror = function() {
                        callback( 500, "Unable to Process Data" );
                    };
                    xdr.onprogress = function() {};
                    if ( s.xdrTimeout ) {
                        xdr.ontimeout = function() {
                            callback( 0, "timeout" );
                        };
                        xdr.timeout = s.xdrTimeout;
                    }
                    xdr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
                },
                abort: function() {
                    if ( xdr ) {
                        xdr.onerror = jQuery.noop();
                        xdr.abort();
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });
}
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Thx so much for your answer. I will have a try.